# Excel - Sum based on another Column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

I know this is some sort of nested equation that I need to use, but I cant sort out the logic. Also, I know this it titled as Excel, but its actually for Google Sheets, I imagine that that shouldnt matter much.

My Table is as follows, I'm trying to automatically calculate the [Difference]:

```
Name        Action        Buy Value        Sell Value        Difference
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
John        BUY           $100             --                --
John        BUY           $50              --                --
John        SELL          --               $200              $50
Sam         BUY           $25              --                -- 
Sam         BUY           $50              --                --
Sam         BUY           $50              --                --
Sam         SELL          --               $100              -$25
```

If the [Action] is "SELL", I need to sum the [Buy Value] if the [Action] is "BUY" and the [Name] matches the "SELL" [Action].

Comment: According to [What are tags and how I should use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) tags should not be included on titles.

Comment: I've not had time to try it but I think the `Query` function might be able to create the summary you're looking for.

Comment: @Rubén no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Prefixing a title with something like  "Excel -" is considered to apply a tag in a title but that is not allowed on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a subtotal row, for each Person, with the sum of Buy Values, Sell Values and Difference of the sums on that row.

```
Name        Action        Buy Value        Sell Value        Difference
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
John        BUY           $100             --                --
John        BUY           $50              --                --
John        SELL          --               $200              --
John        SUBTOTAL      $150 (sum)       $200 (sum)        $50 (Sell - Buy)
Sam         BUY           $25              --                -- 
Sam         BUY           $50              --                --
Sam         BUY           $50              --                --
Sam         SELL          --               $100              --
Sam         SUBTOTAL      $125 (sum)       $100 (sum)        -$25 (Sell - Buy)
```

Comment: Yea this is a decent work around, however since this is actually to track my stock trading, im simply entering my buy/sells and was hoping to find a way to automatically calculate my gains/losses.

Answer (score 0):

I made a comment about using the Google Sheets QUERY function but that may not work if your names on the left are repeated and it also looks like you want the data as it is in your example but automated so...

[image: Example]

This works in Excel but here's a link to copy the Sheets version.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EejBcZ2IdAQArbZv-dlq5obbA4OlD56zkvIhoZWQjKM/copy?usp=sharing

As you can see in my example there is a helper formula in column G

`=IF(B5<>B4,"D"&ROW(),G4)`

The formula populates column G with the Cell address where the name column changes to a new name. The formula in column F can use the value in column G with INDIRECT to create the sum range for the BUY values.

`=IF(C5="SELL",E5-SUM(INDIRECT(G5&":D"&ROW()-1)),"--")`

This automates the value in the Difference column providing the data is arrnged as it is in your example.  I have read that using INDIRECT in a large number of cells can be quite taxing and may affect the performace.